# How to add modifier to user defined command?

Tags: vimscript, command

I'd like to write commands that work with :tab and :vert. Say I have a command that opens a new split window as shown below

```
function! FooSplit()
    let l:message="hello world"
    new
    put! =l:message
endfunction
command! -complete=command Foo call FooSplit()
```

I'd like it to make it so that `:tab Foo` and `:vert Foo` will open in a new tab and vertical split respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:h <mods>](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Cmods%3E) to do this, it expands to modifier or nothing. It's added at [patch 7.4.1898](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/63a60ded3fd584847a05dccf058026e682abad90)

```
command Foo call FooSplit(<q-mods>)

function FooSplit(mods)
  exe a:mods 'new'
endfunction
```

Above example use `<q-mods>` instead of `<mods>`, as you need it as a string.